# MongoDB aggregation - how to add field to every document in array?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Let's say that I have two collections in my database: `actor` and `movie`.

Each movie has a title and I want to add this title field to every document in the `actors` array. I get the `actors` array by using aggregation pipeline together with `$lookup` operation.

My attempt was to `$map` on the `actors` array and add title field. But it doesn't work, unfortunately:

```
db.movie
    .aggregate([
        {
            $lookup: {
                from: 'actor',
                localField: 'id',
                foreignField: 'movie',
                as: 'actors',
            },
        },
        {
            $project: {
                actors: {
                    $map: {
                        input: '$actors',
                        as: 'actor',
                        in: { $set: { title: '$title' } }, // this line doesn't work
                    },
                },
            },
        },
    ])
```

Comment: Could you paste sample documents from both collections ? Do you want those titles to be stored in your collection (update) or just retrieved ?

Comment: Just to retrieve. Right now I'm on mobile, so I can't paste docs :/. Basically I want to get actors array with `title` field taken from the movie collection. I forgot to add that at the beginning of the lookup there is a match operation that filters by id, so I always get one movie document